# Access folders of site without refresh

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh, preloader

I have one doubt has taken me sleep!

First, you can look this website: http://coffeesurfing.illy.com/

I wanna know how get to link other folders of a website without refreshing the page. For example, I access the site for the first time, and the url is "www.site.com/home". So I click in any link, and I go for other folder, like "www.site.com/about", but without refresh. Note that often fade out and show a preloader.

Although the english is bad, I hope to receive many enlightening answers.

Hugs.

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: [History state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries) is what youre looking for.

Comment: @Caramiriel, I've seen the History state, that is good, but I think that it not solves my problem.

Comment: @GláuberSampaio: Well together with [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) I think you should be able to make something similar to what you described in your question. First load the page in the specified element, followed by changing the URL in the history state. Don't forget to subscribe to change events of the history state (such as the back button) to handle those events correctly as well.

Comment: @Caramiriel, But what if someone access the page through a specific URL? History state works like hashtags?

Comment: @GláuberSampaio: Exactly, except for the difference between hashtags and history state is that a history state url points to a valid url. The hashtag just points to one (sometimes multiple) page. With history state the page just loads like a normal page if you access it directly. If you don't want that, you can always use hashtags. In combination with ajax you can use either way.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you mean "How do you create a jQuery-based site navigation?"

Look at the demo here: http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/011_jQuerySite/sample/index.html

If that is what you want, then follow this tutorial:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/